# official module in tensorflow examples at tensorflow.org

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, bert-toolkit

I've been following a tensorflow tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/official_models/fine_tuning_bert

In the first code snippet, I saw a lot of imports from official module

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tfds.disable_progress_bar()

from official.modeling import tf_utils
from official import nlp
from official.nlp import bert

# Load the required submodules
import official.nlp.optimization
import official.nlp.bert.bert_models
import official.nlp.bert.configs
import official.nlp.bert.run_classifier
import official.nlp.bert.tokenization
import official.nlp.data.classifier_data_lib
import official.nlp.modeling.losses
import official.nlp.modeling.models
import official.nlp.modeling.networks
```

And problem is that i found no module name official.
I guess this official module somehow related to problem specific or for BERT model(from tf-hub).
As bert model uses specific text preprocessing and official module is providing this.

So, where i can find, download, use and make imports from this official module to work? I've been using python 3.7, tf-2.2, tf-hub-0.8.0

Please help me out

Comment: Did you read the tag bert?  _DO NOT USE. Use [tag:bert-toolkit] or [tag:bert-rpc]_

Answer (score 2):

The official modules of TensorFlow can be found in the [TensorFlow Model Garden Repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official)

Comment: Thanks, I got complete documentation and installing instructions there.